# sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

Хотел залиться на heroku. Не получилось, вылезла ошибка о том что он не может инсталлировать lzma-native, из-за того, что не хватает прав. Я запускал и из POWERSHELL с админ правами, и git bash с админ правами(судо там незя юзать).
Ребят, подскажите что да как.

```
   Building dependencies
   remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
   remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
   remote:
   remote:        > lzma-native@4.0.3 install /tmp/build_80db413158cbbbed4c86fcd4ab476413/node_modules/lzma-native
   remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && rimraf build
   remote:
   remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
   remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
   remote:        npm ERR! lzma-native@4.0.3 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build && rimraf build
   remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
   remote:        npm ERR!
   remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the lzma-native@4.0.3 install script.
   remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is    likely additional logging output above.
   remote:
   remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.Lwp6m/_logs/2018-11-29T07_49_10_636Z-debug.log
   remote:
   remote: -----> Build failed
```

Comment: Решил добавлением .gitignore с github'a